# Cisco IOS | Can I use same transform set in different crypto maps?

Tags: cisco, vpn, cisco-ios

On a Cisco IOS router can I use the same transform set with multiple crypto maps?

I.E. Is the below configuration example valid?

```
!
crypto isakmp policy 1
 encr aes 256
 authentication pre-share
 group 2
!
crypto isakmp key *** address 192.168.255.1
crypto isakmp key *** address 172.16.255.1
crypto isakmp key *** address 10.255.255.1
!
!
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA esp-3des esp-md5-hmac 
!
!
crypto map CMAP100 1 ipsec-isakmp 
 description *VPN WITH CLIENT 1*
 set peer 192.168.255.1
 set transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA 
 match address 110
!
!
crypto map CMAP200 1 ipsec-isakmp 
 description *VPN WITH CLIENT 2*
 set peer 172.16.255.1
 set transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA 
 match address 120
!
crypto map CMAP200 2 ipsec-isakmp 
 description *VPN WITH CLIENT 3*
 set peer 10.255.255.1
 set transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA 
 match address 130
!
!
!
interface Fa0/0
 description *WAN1*
 ip address 10.0.0.1 255.255.255.0
 crypto map CMAP100
!
interface Fa0/1
 description *WAN2*
 ip address 10.1.0.1 255.255.255.0
 crypto map CMAP200
!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, both transform-sets like ACLs to select interesting traffic can be reused in different crypto maps and different crypto map entries of the same map.